# Open url method not called in app delegate using "https" as url schema in deep linking swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking

Open URL method not called in app delegate using "https" as URL schema in deep linking swift 4
I will attach plist screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

when you want to call deeplink use this from any browser

like safari type yourdeeplink:// or for your deeplink type http://

Comment: I am using in safari like https:// hostname/urlpath

but it's not working

Comment: do you want to pass data from url to app? for example pass urlpath to app and do something

Comment: @JayBhadja You can't use http or https, these are only accessible to safari. You need to create your own scheme, unique to your app. For example the angry birds video game might create one like: `angrybirds://details/user12345678`

Comment: But If I need to create like : https:// details/user/12345678 on click of this link I need to open the screen in the application.